# How to get the angle of a robot arm end tool?

Tags: trigonometry, kinematics, robotics

I need to move a robot arm along a straight line by 10cm.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHth3.png)

The red lines are the current position of the arm.

The blue lines are the position the robot needs to be moved to.

The black lines are just imaginary for the trigonometry.

The 3 green numbers are the angles of the red arm.

The 2 pink numbers are for the blue arm.

The two 5cm lengths at the end of the arm must remain parallel with each other. Also, their Y level must remain the same.

**Notice how the last pink angle is missing. This is the angle that I need to find.**

I made this sketch in Fusion 360, so I know that the missing pink angle is 79.2 degrees.

How do I get the last pink angle?

Comment: I suppose you can use coordinate method. Without coordinates you can find missing angle using triangle with sides 5 cm (blue), and 10 cm, but this calculation will include many steps.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

I had no responses here, so I posted my OP on https://mathforums.com/

There, the user "topsquark" gave an answer:

https://mathforums.com/t/how-to-get-the-angle-of-a-robot-arm-end-tool.365578/

Using topsquark's answer, I was able to do all the math:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMjev.png)